# Google Chrome 33 и Opera 19, при изменении масштаба до 25% - не уменьшают размер букв

Tags: opera, масштабирование, google-chrome

ДО БЕЗУМИЯ РАЗОЗЛИЛ ЭТОТ ФАКТ!!
При уменьшении любой страницы эти браузеры при масштабе в 25% уменьшают только картинки. Буквы остаются такими же по размеру, как и при 33%, в результате (если у меня допустим картинка и текст подогнаны под один размер по ширине и высоте), буквы будут налазить на картинку и выходить за ее пределы. Может быть существует способ НАСИЛЬНО изменить размер текста при изменении масштаба у браузера...
Как ни странно в IE 11 - такого не наблюдается!!! Все уменьшается пропорционально масштабу!
Спасибо заранее за ответы! Перерыл весь инет, но так и не нашел выхода из положения!

Comment: у меня 33 хром. Попробовал масштабировать. Вроде уменьшается нормально.

Comment: >ДО БЕЗУМИЯ РАЗОЗЛИЛ ЭТОТ ФАКТ!!

справедливости ради, этот не слишком уж вопиющий факт сложно отнести к серьезным проблемам вышеуказанных браузеров. А вообще вопрос не по теме

Comment: Хром уменьшает до 33 процентов текст. Далее - не уменьшает. При 25% - происходит уменьшение блоков div, изображений, но текст не уменьшается, в результате все наезжает друг на друга.